# MySQL via Docker container cannot be reached on Linux

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to create a MySQL container purely for testing/learning purposes. If possible, I don't want to deal with extra complexities such as SSL. When I use DBeaver, connecting to
server host: localhost
port: 33060
Database: mysqldb
Username: root
Pasword: secret
Driver name: MySQL

Gives me
"null,  message from server: "Host '172.21.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

The logs for the Docker container is:

```
>docker logs 20ae6
2022-08-30 03:58:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-30 03:58:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-30 03:58:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-30T03:58:17.801333Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-30T03:58:17.803389Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-30T03:58:17.803424Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-30T03:58:17.812663Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-30T03:58:18.068441Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-08-30T03:58:18.405999Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-08-30T03:58:18.406051Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-08-30T03:58:18.408437Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-08-30T03:58:18.434789Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-08-30T03:58:18.434883Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-30T04:00:19.018745Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.30).
2022-08-30T04:00:19.814521Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-08-30 04:00:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-08-30 04:00:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-08-30 04:00:22+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2022-08-30T04:00:23.462649Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-08-30T04:00:23.464620Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-30T04:00:23.464649Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-30T04:00:23.477879Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-08-30T04:00:23.763140Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-08-30T04:00:24.028665Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-08-30T04:00:24.028729Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-08-30T04:00:24.031322Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-08-30T04:00:24.059763Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-08-30T04:00:24.059827Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I start it with

```
docker-compose up
```

using
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    container_name: mysqldb 
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysqldb
      MYSQL_USER: mysqluser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpw
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    networks:
      - db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysqladmin ping -h localhost"
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 60
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - '33060:3306'
networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql:
```

I've tried adding

```
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
```

surrounding it both with ' and ".

and I've also tried it without this.

I also tried adding

```
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

but it doesn't care.

I can see no sign in the log that the DBeaver test connection ever reached it. However, if I give it some other port like 33065 it gives me a connection refused. It's like it reaches some Docker/Networking/Purgatorial limbo that produces no usable output.